# Getting nested frame to fill remaining window space inside parent cell that already fills

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me get my nested frame to fill the remaining window space while inside the cell of it's parent?
I created the application window, gave it a container, gave the container 2 rows and dynamic columns based on how many pages there are. My container is the parent.
I've been able to fill the window with the parent cell by giving weight 1 to the second row and making the 1st column expand to all available columns. I then inserted the nest frame (This is the pages) into the second row, under the buttons for each page in the first row. However, I seem to have trouble with a pack and grid hierarchy, even when I remove all grid usages. It's like tk.Tk() is automatically controlled by grid upon call.

Line 41 seems to be the place where I would be able to do pack fill and expand on the page. But it causes the hierarchy error, even after removing all grid usage and replacing necessary ones with pack. It runs fine without this line by using grid. Just not able to fill/expand

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, page_list):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.minsize(500, 500)
        self.maxsize(500, 500)
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        self.title(title)

#    Create the main container. Row 1 holds page buttons. Row 2 is for the page frame.
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.configure(bg="red")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(len(page_list), weight=1)

#    Begin making the pages and put them in a dictionary to grab by name.
        self.pages = {}
        self.p_names = page_list
        for P in self.p_names:
            page_name = P.__name__
            page = P(parent=container, controller=self, title=page_name.strip("Page"))
            self.pages[page_name] = page
#    Make the buttons from the page list provided
        self.create_buttons(container, self)

        self.show_page(str(self.p_names[0].__name__), self.currentPage)

    def show_page(self, page_name, button):
        self.currentPage.configure(relief="raised", bg="red", fg="black")
        page = self.pages[page_name]

#    Put the page in row 1 below the buttons, in the top left. Expand it so it fills the remainder of the cell/window
        #page.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true") #This line will cause error when uncommented.
        page.grid(row=1, columnspan=len(self.pages), sticky="nw")

        for p in self.pages:
            if p != page_name:
                self.pages[p].grid_forget()
        button.configure(relief="sunken", bg="black", fg="white")
        self.currentPage = button

    def create_buttons(self, s, controller):
        pgs = len(self.p_names)*3
#    need to figure out how to accurately get window width and use it properly for button width division
        pages = {}

        for i,p in enumerate(self.p_names):
            pages[i] = tk.Button(s, text=p.__name__.strip("Page"), fg="Black", bg="red",
                                 width=(self.winfo_reqwidth() // pgs) + 1,
                                 command=lambda i=i, p=p: controller.show_page(p.__name__, pages[i]))
            pages[i].grid(row=0, column=i)
        self.currentPage = pages[0]


class NewPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        self.title = title
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="Black")
        self.controller = controller

#    Create Page Title Label
        pageTitle = tk.Label(self, text=self.title, font=controller.title_font, bg="Black", fg="white")
#    Attempt to fill cell that page is in
        pageTitle.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        pageTitle.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        pageTitle.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
#    Pad the page title
        pageTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky="nsew")


        #extraLabel = tk.Label(self, text="test", bg="blue")
        #extraLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, sticky="nsew")


class CharacterPage(NewPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        super().__init__(parent, controller, title)


class OptionsPage(NewPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        super().__init__(parent, controller, title)


class InventoryPage(NewPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        super().__init__(parent, controller, title)


class RandomPage(NewPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        super().__init__(parent, controller, title)


def main():
    app = Application("Game Title Here", [CharacterPage, InventoryPage, OptionsPage])
    app.mainloop()


main()
```

What should happen is the page, because it's background is black, should cover the remainder of the cell/window in black. The coloring  is for me to visually see that it's working, not just to make the background black. The page will eventually be populated with other elements.

Am I missing something about pack or grid? I'm fairly new to using them. About a week or 2 only. **Couldn't find anything on nested frame filling.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use pack and grid in the same container.

Try giving the page a different bg color so you can tell when you see it:

```
class NewPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):
        self.title = title
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="tan")    # bg='tan'
```

you will see that the page sits in the upper left corner. In the middle or the page is the label `pageTitle`.

Use `sticky="nwse"` to expand page to fill the cell.

Comment: the top left corner is the desired position. The problem is that the page does not expand to fill the area. The page should fill in the remainder of the cell. The container is red, and i can tell it properly fills the window because the background becomes red. The background of the page is black. I can tell it does not fill it's remaining area because the page is still red while only the area of the label (page title) is black. I originally had ``sticky="ne" `` as ``sticky="nsew"`` which put it in the middle. Even then, it did not fill.

Comment: Also, as a note, I'm able to use pack first then grid configure right after establishing the container. Is this not supposed to be able to happen?

Comment: I think you misstake the label inside the page for the page. Try my new suggestion.

Comment: You can configure a frame for grid even if you pack it.

Comment: Ah, I see what I overlooked. Thank you for pointing that out.

To make it a little clearer for anyone who reads this:

In line 66, I make my frame the same color as my label, which led me astray whenever I attempted to differentiate the label from the page.
So we made my page background tan.
Then in line 42, due to my misdirection earlier, my thoughts on how I was manipulating the label and page was skewed. I had put the page in the top left corner thinking it would fill the page with pack. Putting it sticky to all directions fixed this.